# What's the ATL way to open a named pipe in windows in c++?

Tags: c++, winapi, atl

```
hPipe = CreateFile( 
         lpszPipename,   // pipe name 
         GENERIC_READ |  // read and write access 
         GENERIC_WRITE, 
         0,              // no sharing 
         NULL,           // default security attributes
         OPEN_EXISTING,  // opens existing pipe 
         0,              // default attributes 
         NULL);          // no template file
```

How to convert the above to `ATL` way so that the pipe is automatically closed when the COM component is destroyed?

Comment: When what COM component is destroyed?

Answer (score 6):

I have to guess what COM component you are referring to, since your post was vague.  But I'm guessing you have written a COM component that wraps or otherwise uses a named pipe, and you want it to be automatically released (ala [RAII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Resource_Acquisition_Is_Initialization)) when this COM component is destroyed.

In this case, you would put any cleanup code in the component's [FinalRelease()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ea0ca499(VS.80).aspx) method, for example:

```
void CoMyObject::FinalRelease()
{
  CloseHandle(my_pipe_handle_);
}
```

The other side of the one-time-cleanup coin is one-time-initialization code. If you also want to open this named pipe when the COM component is instantiated -- which your title suggests but your post doesn't say -- then you would do this in your object's [FinalConstruct()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/afkt56xx(v=VS.80).aspx) method:

```
HRESULT CoMyObject::FinalConstruct()
{
  my_pipe_handle_ = CreateFile( 
         lpszPipename,   // pipe name 
         GENERIC_READ |  // read and write access 
         GENERIC_WRITE, 
         0,              // no sharing 
         NULL,           // default security attributes
         OPEN_EXISTING,  // opens existing pipe 
         0,              // default attributes 
         NULL);          // no template file }

  return S_OK;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlfile.h>

CAtlFile m_file;
m_file.Create(lpszPipeName, GENERIC_READ|GENERIC_WRITE, 0, OPEN_EXISTING);
```

Presumably, m_file is a member variable of your class.  When your class instance gets its final release (and subsequently destroyed), the destructor of m_file will close the handle associated with the pipe.